# Laravel 5 -- Redirect in Controller is not working in AJAX call

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

***Important***: this comes from ajax call.

Everything works perfectly except:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;

public function my_call() {
 return redirect()->route('page-1');
}
```

Throws 500 error.

*return view('page-1')* works without problems. 
Maybe anybody sees what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an actual route with the name that you are using, you cannot redirect to a view as these are returned by routes

Comment: I've tried return view('page-1') and it returns raw html.

Comment: what you are returning there is a view not a route so it will work however if you are redirecting from a controller you must redirect to a route and then that route can return your view

Comment: I have edited my question by adding not that this comes from AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly you cannot do this on server side if you do **AJAX** call:/

Here an explanation: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/redirect-after-ajax-post-request

It's for vue but I believe it applies universally for ajax.